# Swift - Moving a row within one tableView section causes the headers of other sections to be reloaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is a long one so I appreciate your time! I'm having trouble with reordering rows in a particular section of a UITableView.

**The Context:** I have a UITableView (.plain style) with multiple sections. Section 0 has a display of a lot of information. Section 1 is a list of users who have liked some content. Section 2 is another list of users who have disliked some content. Section 3 is a list of comments generated by users. Each cell and header view in the table are custom classes initiated from nibs. I allow users to sort the comments based on popularity. When a user taps on the sort button, the following function is called:

```
func sortOnPopular() {

    if self.comments.isEmpty {
        return
    }

    self.table.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: self.COMMENT_SEC), at: .top, animated: true)

    //FIREBASE method
    //returns a child from a node on the database that is sorted
    //according to the parameter passed to it. The function returns
    //each child one by one according to its rank in the sort.
    _ = ref.child("not really important...").queryOrdered(byChild: "not important also").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        //Gets the index, i, of the sorted comment in the model, keys.
        if let i = self.keys.index(of: snapshot.key) {
            self.table.beginUpdates()
            self.table.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row:i, section: self.COMMENT_SEC), to: IndexPath(row:0, section:self.COMMENT_SEC))
            self.keys.remove(at: i)
            self.keys.insert(snapshot.key, at: 0)
            self.table.endUpdates()
        }
    })
}
```

**The Problem:** This code used to work beautifully when I only had one section in the table view. Once I added more than one, the table view would do strange things when this function was called. For example, the main content display (Section 0) would appear to get reloaded. After the user taps the sort button, which is in Section 0, its color is changed to orange. The button will remain orange for a short time, but, once the sorting is finished, it reverts back to its original color. It is supposed to stay orange until the user taps the button again. I have images in Section 0 that also appear to get re-downloaded when this function is called. The background of the header for Section 0 is a visual effect dark blur view; when this function is called, it no longer blurs - it appears to be a slightly transparent black view. Moreover, when this function is called, all of the headers shift upwards and then back to their original positions.

Based on all that, I think this function is somehow causing the table view to reload all of its sections and rows.

**The Questions:**

(1) Does calling tableView.moveRow(at:to:) reload the entire tableView? If so, is there a way to restrict the updates to a particular section?

(2) The documentation doesn't say that it's necessary to use the tableView.beginUpdates() and .endUpdates() unless you're inserting or deleting rows. Are they necessary here?

(3) Inserting rows to the tableView also produces the result described above concerning the rendering of the UIVisualEffectView. Has anybody had this experience?

Thanks for your patience and any advice you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears fine, however we may have to consider cases where the cells are beyond the view area and when we reuse the cells.

I observe that when we move the row using

`tableView.moveRow(at: , to: )`

or also when we scroll using

`tableView.scrollToRow(at: , at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)`

along with it during cell reuse, the results are inconsistent.

So it's good to reload just that comments section using

`reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet, with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)`

after you sort your data. This will reload that section and avoid hassles of reused cells.

Hope this helps.